# video view in landscape

Tags: java, android, web-services, video

how to play video view in a small size in portrait
and full screen in landscape?

```
 Uri uri = Uri.parse(videoDetail.getVideoPath());
    //   Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://daily3gp.com/vids/747.3gp");

    VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoPlayer);

    MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
    mediaController.setMediaPlayer(videoView);




    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
    videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
    videoView.start();
```

Comment: and how to say the resolution of video?

Answer (score 2):

1>To play video in landscape and in full mode

add in your manifest file

`<activity
            android:name=".youractivityname"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >`

and in your .xml file add this

`<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     >
    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_gravity="fill" /></RelativeLayout>`

2> To play video in small size

`<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >`

no need to use android:screenOrientation

because default is in portrait

and in your xml file

`

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1" >



    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_gravity="fill" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

`

Hope this will help you...

Comment: you know, it is 1 video for play in landscape and portrait!

Comment: couldn't get you can you please elaborate your question.

Comment: i have a video. when my phone is in portrait situation it has a size, and in landscape situation i want to to be full screen

Answer (score 0):

Try somethin like below:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);


    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
int left = videoView .getLeft();
            int top = videoView .getTop();
            int right = left + (width);
            int botton = top + (height);
            videoView .layout(left, top, right, bottom);

    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        int left = videoView .getLeft();
            int top = videoView .getTop();
            int right = left + (width / 2);
            int botton = top + (height / 2);
            videoView .layout(left, top, right, bottom);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this.Define two layout one will use full screen and in other define the layout width height and position you want.And define this code in the activity class.

`@Override

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) 
{
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);


    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) 
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.fullscreen);

    } 
    else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.potrait);

    }
}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == 1)
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.landscape);
    }
    if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == 2)
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.potrait);
    }
```

}`

Comment: it's layout name like abc.xml . use my below defined two xml.

Comment: u have 2 xml file here. when u turn mobile from landscape to portrait , it will begins from the first as a new video

Answer (score 0):

what happened is that current VideoView Activity (landscape) is destroyed, a new VideoView Activity (portrait) is created due screenOrientation configuration has been changed, and destoryed immidiately (where you can see the effects on screen).Try to use activity life cycle

See if it works

`     @Override

protected void onResume() {

```
mVideoView.resume();
super.onResume();
```

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {

```
mVideoView.suspend();
super.onPause();
```

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {

```
mVideoView.stopPlayback();
super.onDestroy();
```

}`

Comment: thanks, I have another question. I  have a video that I call it from web service. can I say the video t play in a specific resolution. I mean that videoView has a property to show video in for example 360p? how?

Comment: Sure you can ask,but I think i will be better if you can post it separately.

Comment: i'm blocked and cannot ask more question :(

Comment: Sorry to hear that. See the video resolution depends on the phone resolution and android-version .You can't handle completely on every devices.Here is the link where you can get your every details  http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html